# How to set adaptive web design in ExpressionEngine

Tags: php, ee

I am new in web development. and I wants to use the adaptive web designs in expression engine. can any help me that how we will use multiple screen sizes (Desktop, Mobile, Tablet) templates in expression engine. for example if we are saying home page template then i wanna create 3 different templates for home page. 1 for mobile 1 for tablet and 1 for desktop. system will automatically detect the device. my question is how to use multiple templates for home page.

**Adaptive Web Design:**

Adaptive web design is different from responsive design in that there isn’t one layout that always changes. Instead, there are several distinct layouts for multiple screen sizes. And the layout used depends on the screen size used. For example, there could be a specific layout for mobile phones, tablets, and desktop computers – each of which are made in advance. These three designs wait on standby until someone visits the site. The site detects the type of device used, and delivers the pre-set layout for that device.  So instead of a single ball going through several different-sized hoops, you’d have several different balls to use depending on the hoop size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExpressionEngine was made to be a blank slate,  is a design- and content-agnostic CMS. What does this mean?

Unlike WordPress and some other CMS, ExpressionEngine adapts to your design rather than the reverse.

It is template-drive, not theme-driven, and your templates may contain any code you want, including JavaScript, HTML, XML, JSON, etc.

It is a powerful tool for developing customized websites without compromising on layout or features.

Comment: Very well explained. Short and sweet!